Getting "undeclared attribute type for enum, Enums must be backed by a database column" error, but the enum ~is~ backed by a database column
Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? Rails 7.2.0.
I am getting this error on #status and #billing_status attributes when running any test related to the Tournament model:
RuntimeError: Undeclared attribute type for enum 'status' in Tournament. Enums must be backed by a database column or declared with an explicit type via `attribute`.

However, these attributes on my Tournament model are backed by database columns:
from db/schema.rb:
  create_enum "tournament_billing_status", ["pending", "paid", "canceled", "rejected", "failed"]
  create_enum "tournament_status", ["started", "created", "linked", "registering", "in_progress", "completed"]

  create_table "tournaments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "account_id"
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "email"
    t.date "start_date"
    t.enum "status", default: "started", enum_type: "tournament_status"
    t.enum "billing_status", default: "pending", enum_type: "tournament_billing_status"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["account_id"], name: "index_tournaments_on_account_id"
  end

I am using the new syntax for enum declaration in my model:
from app/models/tournament.rb:
  class Tournament < ApplicationRecord
    broadcasts_refreshes

    belongs_to :account

    validates :first_name, :last_name, :email, presence: true

    enum :status, {
      started: "started",
      created: "created",
      linked: "linked",
      registering: "registering",
      in_progress: "in_progress",
      completed: "completed"
    }

    enum :billing_status, {
      pending: "pending",
      paid: "paid",
      canceled: "canceled",
      rejected: "rejected",
      failed: "failed"
    }
  end

If I add these two lines to the model, above the enum declarations, the tests pass:
  attribute :status, :string
  attribute :billing_status, :string

But I shouldn't have to do that, right?
I'm stumped. Any help is appreciated.

Do you really want to use enum types here? Because of their inflexibility I wouldn't recommend it for cases where the number of potential states is not finite and unchanging.

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/52607

What happens if you rename your columns to tournament_status and tournament_billing_status?

@max The potential states here are fairly finite and unchanging. Personally, I've had a positive experience using enums for this type of thing in the past.

@LukeAbel Same result.

@engineersmnky Thanks so much for the link - that seems to be my exact issue, I hadn't seen it.

As pointed out by @engineersmnky, this was a Rails bug related to changes in enum handling, per: github.com/rails/rails/issues/52607.
A fix that reverts the enum changes was merged, reasoning that having PG break on enums is worse than not handling the rare case of a non-database-backed enum.
A workaround until you get the fix is to disable parallel testing with multiple workers.
